# Place a panel on the lower corner of page in BootstrapCSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I am using BootstrapCSS 3 in order to make a map application. I have created a panel as following:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#legendpane">
                <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
                Legend
              </a>

            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="legendpane" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div id = "listedAttributes" class="panel-body list-group" style="max-height: 200px; overflow-y:scroll;">
                <img src="static/img/legend.png" alt="legend" width="185" height="147">
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>
```

What I want is to place this panel on the button of the page. And when the page is autoresized to remain there (on the lower right corner). I tried to use margin-top: x% or maging-buttom but it doesn't give the result I want.
Its not responsive.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
bottom: 10px;
position: fixed;
float: left;
```

to `<div class="panel-heading">` in your css

Comment: Maybe with position: fixed and float:left ?

Comment: Thanks! This works very good if I place it in the parent of the div you suggested: <div class="panel panel-default" style="position: fixed; float: left; bottom: 2%;"> The problem is that for some reason the width of the legend changes by it self. I can add in the style the "width" value though.

Comment: If you edit your answer I will accept it as correct. Thanks.